# Azure IoT Edge Yocto Project Support

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are building Azure IoT Edge by getting the meta-iotedge layer from the URL below with Yocto Project Version 2.5 (sumo).

https://github.com/Azure/meta-iotedge

The latest version of the meta-iotedge layer is 1.0.10, But Ubnutu Linux has released versions 1.1 and 1.2 of Azure IoT Edge runtime. Please tell me the plan to support meta-iotedge layer versions 1.1 and 1.2.

Comment: Related question: https://github.com/Azure/meta-iotedge/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

The repo targets the latest LTS release of IoT Edge and an active LTS release of yocto (currently Dunfell).

https://github.com/Azure/meta-iotedge#branching-strategy-and-timelines

Comment: Dunfell is not the current LTS. Kirkstone is. Azure needs to catch up.